# Cloud SQL Admin Api Warning in GCF

Tags: mysql, api, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql

I have a function deployed in GCF which is executed in node js. And it works with Cloud SQL instance of MySQL.
And I receive this warning from time to time.

> CloudSQL warning: your action is needed to update your function and avoid potential disruptions. Please see https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/sql#troubleshooting for additional details: ensure that the account has access to "***-mysql-dev7" (and make sure there's no typo in that name). Error during createEphemeral for ***-mysql-dev7: googleapi: Error 403: Cloud SQL Admin API has not been used in project 319049*** before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/sqladmin.googleapis.com/overview?project=319049**** then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry., accessNotConfigured

And after this warning function continues to execute. What does it mean? Why function is not halted. If it is not important what does it mean and what if I don't enable this admin API?
BTW function only does selects and updates, it doesn't change table structure so theoretically why would it need Admin API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand the confusion that warning messages may bring, especially if they have no noticeable effects on your function’s workflow.

To the best of my knowledge, the warning identifies that through not enabling this API, there will be potential for further issues when in need of performing certain tasks which require the [Cloud SQL Admin API](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api#console). Potential uses for the Cloud SQL Admin API can be found under [public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/rest).  If you would ever need to list the Cloud SQL instances in a project, get the database of a particular instance, create a new Cloud SQL instance, or perform any other operation listed, please enable the API.

To avoid seeing these warnings all together, I would recommend enabling the API.

EDIT:

Cloud Functions utilizes a mechanism to [connect to Cloud SQL instances via the Cloud SQL proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-functions#connecting_to), the Cloud SQL proxy in turn [utilizes the Cloud SQL Admin API](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-functions#api-quota-limits).

Therefore when connecting to a Cloud SQL instance without the Cloud SQL Admin API enabled, the error message is thrown.

Cloud Functions is still able to connect to the Cloud SQL instance as it utilizes a legacy connection mechanism when it is unable to do so via the Cloud SQL proxy.

This is why the function does not halt and can still perform the operations on the instance as expected.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! The problem is that it says "Error during createEphemeral" - so it already tries to call one of Cloud SQL Admin functions implicitely and failes, but still manages to continue. We don't use this function in our code. For connections we use library 'mysql'

Comment: No worries, we are happy to assist! Google Cloud Functions inherently utilize the Google Cloud Admin API when [connecting to Cloud SQL instances](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-functions#api-quota-limits). When connecting to an instance via Cloud Functions, [an internal mechanism utilizes the Cloud SQL proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-functions#connecting_to), which in turn utilizes the Cloud SQL Admin API.

Comment: You are right! If Cloud Sql instance and Cloud function are in different GCP then Cloud SQL proxy is used. That's a huge help, thank you!
The question remains how it worked at all without Cloud Sql Admin Api. I guess there is some failover mechanism to connect to Cloud Sql without Cloud SQL proxy (maybe usual connection via IP address)

Comment: I would just like to clarify on some things here so that I may proceed in assisting you appropriately. From my understanding, even if the Cloud SQL Admin API was not enabled, you are capable of connecting to your Cloud SQL instance and can then perform the Select and Update operations respectively?

Comment: Exactly. The Warning was logged, but selects and updates still executed correctly

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I am in the process of inquiring with the Cloud Functions specialist team in order to gain a definite answer on the above behavior. Please do expect a update within 24hrs, or as soon as there are pertinent details available to provide on the behavior seen here.

Comment: Apologies for not updating you in time, I am awaiting clarification from the Cloud Functions specialists on the mentioned behavior as of now. Please expect a update on August 10 or as soon as there are any details I can provide you with.

Comment: Thanks! Looking forward for the answer

Comment: Just to let you know that I am awaiting clarification from the Cloud Functions specialists in determining the behavior found here. Will update here as soon as I receive updates to provide.

Comment: Hey there, Cloud Functions is able to successfully connect and operate on the instance as it does utilize a legacy mechanism to connect to the SQL instance when the Admin API is not enabled. I hope this answers your question!

Answer (score 0):

Enabling [**Cloud SQL Admin API**](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/sqladmin.googleapis.com/overview?) will solve the warning:

[image]